# Angular $resource with path variable

Tags: angularjs

I defined the following service:

```
myServices.factory('MyManager', ['$resource',
    function ($resource) {
        return $resource('../rest/contract/:contractId', {contractId:'@contractId'}, {
            findById: {method: 'GET', contractId: '@contractId'}
        });
    }]);
```

I want to make the REST call and, in my controller, I am doing this:

```
MyManager.findById(contractId,
            // on success
            function (response) {
                // do
            },
            // on error
            function () {
                alert("Error");
            });
```

However, the generated URL is `<base>/rest/contract` and no path variable is appended. The parameter I am passing to findById is not null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the parameter as an object:

```
MyManager.findById({contractId: contractId}, ...
```